# GZip decompression of SQL database blob

Tags: c#, gzip

I'm trying to load a .mbtiles database into a C# application, and relevant data that I need to finalise my project is stored in a var_blob column in my database. I've been told that the data is compressed and GZip should be able to decompress it, but I can't seem to find anything relating to this.

I'm not even sure how to go about doing this. Do I try and load the (rather large) blob in as a string and then use a byte array? Just typing that out makes it sound ridiculous.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** for reference the database is an SQLite db.

Comment: You can save byte array using sqlite to blob. If you retrieve it, then it is also a byte array and use gzip decompress to decompress it.

Comment: @Stanley thank you, I'll have a dig around now.